# codeigniter user authentication library that works with sqlite

Tags: sqlite, codeigniter

Is there a codeigniter user authentication library that works well with sqlite3?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most of the authentication libraries should work with sqlite unless:

- They don't use CI's ActiveRecord
- They use Database-specific functions

Check the library for all these.

Comment: I finally got ion auth to work with sqlite3 via pdo on codeigniter 1.7.2.I however had to do lots of changes to the model.

Comment: Hey ObjectiveME - do you have a sample of these changes posted to git or anywhere I could look at them?  I'm trying to do the same thing and it's a taking a long time.